What is the highest apogee of a satellite in Earth orbit?
An Alien craft is approaching Earth and has detected satellites in Earth orbit (and many other strange phenomenon). Although the satellites have been detected, for various out of scope reasons they are not recognized for what they are. The aliens need to investigate and need to go into orbit around the Earth avoiding all artificial satellites.
What is the highest apogee of a satellite in Earth orbit they need to avoid? Ignore any satellites in Solar or lunar orbit.
Edit to answer some of the questions raised
All artificial satellites are in scope operational or not. Space Junk is in scope if it is significant. Booster stages and objects more than 1 metre in diameter. Objects orbiting the Moon can be ignored as can objects orbiting Mars.

What research have you performed? (And this seriously appears to be a non-worldbuilding question asking for free research.) Are operational satellites the only class of object we're considering? Does space junk (artificial "stuff") qualify? What about satellites orbiting the moon, which is technically a satellite orbiting Earth? How about satellites orbiting Mars?

Why do they need to orbit above all artificial satellites? Space is big, and except for low Earth orbit and geosynchronous orbit the risk of collision is vanishingly small. They can safely orbit at a height of 15,000km, well above LEO but below geosynchronous orbit, especially if the orbit is inclined to the equator.

@JBH I have performed sufficient research to know that this is a non trivial question and if you don't want to answer the question you don't have to.

@Mike Scott space is big but the aliens don't want to disturb or approach anything in Earth orbit as the phenomena of so many small satellites is novel to them. Perhaps they should stop a lot further out. The idea of using a polar orbit is a good idea.

It must be pointed out that the “apogee” being the highest point of a satellite’s orbit around the Earth, “highest apogee” is a pleonasm, as the apogee is already the highest…

It's not a pleonasm as the question involves a series of apogees. Orbits vary and some apogees are greater than others. I am looking for the orbit with the highest apogee.

And yet you didn't address any of my questions asking for clarification. It's certainly non-trivial if you're expecting us to read your mind.

Are you concerned about stuff at the Lagrange points? If so, that's the farthest something can orbit without being dominated by the sun. Otherwise, a quick Google search reveals that some satellites studying solar wind get up as high as 470,310 km.

@JBH I edited the question yesterday to address some of your concerns

Try asking on: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/

There are over a hundred satellites in Molniya orbit, a few tens in Tundra orbit and a handful in really high earth orbits. The first two of those go above geostationary orbit; there are examples of the last with perigee of at least 375,000km.
The last of these are not much more common in near-Earth space than asteroids of similar sizes, but they'll  still spoil your day if you collide with one.
If space-travelling aliens don't realise that lots of small bodies orbiting a planet that's emitting plenty of radio and radar signals are likely to be artificial satellites, the explanation is going to have to be quite good.

That is useful thankyou. The aliens are in fact a machine intelligence that has emerged into our space from else where and has been surveying our locality. Lots of stars, lots of planets but no life until they discover Earth, Which is bewildering to them.

James Webb Space Telescope, at the Earth-Sun L2 point, is roundly a million miles from Earth, but still gravitationally bound to the Earth-Moon system.
Other than that, there are very few if any permanent satellites beyond the "graveyard orbits" used to park expired geostationary satellites.  These are typically only a few hundred kilometers higher than geosynchronous, however, so roundly if they're well beyond the 24 hour orbital period, they'd be well clear of anything we put up intentionally and left there.

JWST is orbiting mainly the Sun

@fraxinus If JWST were exactly at the L2 point, the Earth and Sun would have exactly equal influence over its orbit by definition. IIRC it's actually kept very slightly Earthward of that balance point and periodically boosted towards it, but not enough that I'd really call it "orbiting Earth".

JWST is orbiting the L2 point, not the Earth

Chance for Collision
Knowing the apogee of a satellite is not the same as knowing where the satellite currently is... The farthest apogee might be the first that would be able to collide with the ship, but the chances that the satellite is exactly at this spot are miniscule (unless plot relevant ofc).
Populated Orbits
Are you aware of stuffinspace? There you can see a realtime map of all registered satellites and debris. Pretty impressive. You will notice that there are denser populated areas or "belts" your aliens need to avoid/handle somehow.
Here is another overview of the most common earth-bound orbits on wikimedia commons (animated).
Wide, excentric Orbits
Then there is stuff, mostly debris, that is more critical, because by nature those pieces are very fast, the orbit is not stable, so it changes a little every round and the kinetic energy would be able to penetrate any hull that is not specifically designed to withstand such impacts. For example, this debris of an Iridium satellite - at the time of writing at altitude ~366,000km and counting, spiralling outwards at 1km/s (the map does not mention a size or weight though. But it is big enough to be trackable obviously).
There is a big one!
The Moon. Apogee approx. 404,000km.

Very useful - thanks. The Moon is in scope (but is very detectable). The Iridium satellite is rather odd...I will see where it is tomorrow

I figured the moon would be a corner case (it is also not artificial) but I wondered why a small satellite would matter more than a big one. -- The debris irritates me as well. It is not on an outward spiral, as I initially thought. It has a strange alternating, but regular, orbital pattern. Still way out of the designated 624km apogee/perigee orbit.

The Iridium debris seems to be an error. It has an impossibly short period for its altitude of 97.25 minutes, and a search for the designator reveals it's no longer in orbit.

The terms 'perigee' and 'apogee' refer to the closest and furthest point that some body get to with respect to Earth. It is easy to define points for bodies with elliptical orbits about Earth. It would be very odd to apply the terms to the Sun, to comets, or to the other planets. 'Perigee' is used for the closest approach of asteroids that nearly miss Earth. I see no logical reason why the both terms should not apply to objects such as Cruithne, in 1:1 resonance with the Earth about the Sun. In which case the perigee is about 12 million km, and the apogee is further than the other side of the Earth's orbit.
As you get closer to Earth, the density of space junk increases until atmospheric drag makes the orbits unstable. If I was in a flying saucer, I would avoid the geostationary and graveyard orbits, and avoid lingering in the plane of the ecliptic where a lot of the other satellites like. I would carry some protection against very small objects such as paint chips, look out for the bigger objects, and go in and out quickly to keep the total risk down.
I appreciate this is not an answer to your literal question, but I hope it may answer the underlying problem.

Additional Info: The general term for extremes on an orbit is apsis. The terms aphelion and perihelion apply to orbits around the sun for example.

TESS has an apogee of about 375,000 km. Few orbits of such dimensions are stable against lunar perturbations, but TESS is in a stable 2:1 resonance with the Moon.
